# expand macro in single byte encoded code

Tags: errors, expansion, preamble, input-encodings

In this minimal (not) working example, I try to use single-byte `latin10`-encoded source file, and expand a command-macro containing a character with `\catcode254`:

```
    % -*- mode: latex; unibyte: t; coding: iso-8859-16 -*-
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin10]{inputenc}

    \newcommand\mwe{Lista de demonstrații}

    \begin{document}

      \chapter{Oscilații}

      \xdef\MWE{\mwe}

      \MWE

    \end{document}
```

but I get this "`\crcr`" error in the log:

```
    ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \MWE.
    <to be read again> 
                       \crcr 
    l.14 \xdef\MWE{\mwe
                       }
```

If (*file is **not** UTF-8!*) I replace the `ț` (`\catcode254`) with `ș` (`\catcode186`), same error.

Instead, if I replace with `â` (`\catcode226`) or with just `t`, the error disappears.

These `latin10` letters are for Southeastern European languages.

The useful code I need for a `\LaTeX` class is related with `\addcontentsline`; here is another example:

```
    % -*- mode: latex; unibyte: t; coding: iso-8859-16 -*-

    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin10]{inputenc}

    \newcommand\mwe{Lista de demonstrații}
    \newcommand\toc[2]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}

    \begin{document}

      \makeatletter
      \@expandtwoargs\toc{\mwe}{}
      \makeatother

    \end{document}
```

and the log:

```
    ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
    <to be read again> 
                       \crcr 
    l.14 \@expandtwoargs\toc{\mwe}{}
```

What is about this behavior? I appreciate any help.

Thank s.

Unicode (i.e., `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`) is not a solution here, since these `latin10`-encoded lines come from `\TeX` text input streams (`\immediate\read`), hence the single-byte constraint.

Comment: You mean `charcode` not `\catcode`, right?

Comment: Yes, i meant i typeset `\catcode254=12` just before `\read`, so i was just hinting.

Comment: Ok, because "a character with `\catcode254`" doesn't make much sense. You probably mean "the character `\char254` with catcode 12".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@David: `\catcode254` is the catcode of character 254, likely 13.  I have to admit some astonishment about your statement, but then the original poster also uses this wrongly, likely meaning `\char254`.

There is always the possibility of using eTeX features for sidestepping LaTeX's protection issues:

```
\edef\MWE{\unexpanded\expandafter{\mwe}}
```

In the particular issue of using LaTeX's write commands, however, `\protected@xdef` seems like the way to go: writing typically involves several staggered ways of expansion, and anticipating them means knowing the effect of LaTeX internals.  The above `\edef`, in contrast, operates from the assumption that `\mwe` will work in the given context, and produces something equivalent.

One can also add "ultimate" protection by using `\protected\edef` followed by the above.  In the given application, it would then write out the 8bit character unchanged, whereas LaTeX's default would be to write the LICR (LaTeX internal character representation), something like \d{t} or so.  Consequently being fit for getting read back in even under different input encodings.

Comment: I'm getting too old for this game I'll delete the catcode remark, thanks:-)+1  It's true that protected edef would work here but probably other packages will make unprotected definitions and so the basic point that using xdef is in general unsafe still stands.

Comment: @DavidKastrup: The `@user` syntax only works within the comments of the same posts, not between posts. You might want to post a comment in addition to your answer next time. Also, I just saw that your account is still unregistered. You might want to register it properly, otherwise you might loose access to it after a while, e.g. if your session cookie expires etc.

Comment: This `\@expandtwoargs\toc{\unexpanded\expandafter{\mwe}}{}` is needed for a `\prelim@contents` i employed (from Sergio Gelato's cornell class, but with \inputenconding{latin10} `\read` macros), thank s.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: as you can see, I only use this "account" to answer people.  The "privileges" are not available without registering, and I don't need to feed my data into another address harvester and keep track of another password and associated usage conditions.  If I would actually start to care, it would be time anyway to get rid of another time sink, so "losing access" would be just the thing.

Comment: @DavidKastrup: I just mentioned it, in case you simply forgot to register. Your name and email address are already in the system, so there wouldn't be any change here.

Answer (score 4):

If I run your example I get

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \MWE.
<to be read again> 
                   \crcr 
l.12       \xdef\MWE{\mwe
```

Active characters are made robust using the LaTeX `\protect` mechanism but that only works if you use the LaTeX mechanisms. `\xdef` will break any fragile command. If you change your document to

```
\makeatletter
      \protected@xdef\MWE{\mwe}
\makeatother
```

It runs for me without error.

Comment: Ok, thanks, actually i have a `my@def[2]` interface for defining macros, where i employed \xdef; i will use `\protected@xdef` now. For the MWE i presented, it works.